# NetCDF to CSV with loop

Tags: loops, csv, netcdf

I wrote this code to extract data from NetCDF file into CSV file using specific latitude and longitude. My problem is that, every time the new produced CSV file includes the former values. The results from every iteration added to the previous results and CSV No.3 includes the value of CSV No.1 and No.2. It makes the process so slow. Is there any way to manage that? 
Thank you.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = xr.open_mfdataset('D:/data/Control/*.nc')

time = data.variables['time']
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
tmax = data.variables['tmax'][:]

longs=[28.57,30.30,32.03,33.76,35.49,37.22,38.95,40.68,42.41,44.14,45.87,47.60,49.33]

t0=153
result=[]
result1=[]

for j in longs: 
    df=data.sel(lat=-105.48,lon=j, method='nearest')
    splits=[120,485,850,1216,1581,1946,2311,2677,3042,3407,3772,4138,4503,4868,5233,5599,
        5964,6329,6694,7060,7425,7790,8155,8521,8886,9251,9616,9982,10347,10712]
    for i in splits:
        time3=df.variables['time'][i:(i+t0)]
        dg=df.sel(time=time3, method ='nearest')  
        result.append(dg.tmax)
    np.savetxt("con-105-{0}.csv".format(j), result, fmt="%s")
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the size of your dataset. However, netCDFs are often not optimized for time series access. This can be improved by applying chunking in the time dimension using `nccopy`. If your dataset is not huge I think it would be better to concatenate across time first, using `ncrcat`, rather than use `open_mfdataset`. If your dataset is huge I suggest doing all of the above, split up into spatial tiles. More than you were asking for!

Comment: The size of my dataset s huge. is nccopy a function for windows or Linux?